# problems with vim re-evaluating augroup

Tags: vim

Vim7.4, mac.

This is a small function to set some settings, based on file type to write prose.

If i start by opening for example my vimrc everything is fine, this works as expected, but if from my vimrc i open a markdown file, then attempt to got to a different unspecified file type, the `augroup au!` is not reevaluated and the settings remain. Can somebody explain why this is and possibly provide a solution.

```
func! WordProcessorMode()
    set foldcolumn=12
    setlocal formatoptions=a
    setlocal foldmethod=expr foldexpr=TexFold()
    setlocal spell spelllang=en_us textwidth=80
endfu

augroup Prose
    au!
    au FileType markdown :call WordProcessorMode()
    au FileType plaintex :call WordProcessorMode()
augroup END
```

Answer (score 1):

The `au!` command is only there for when you source the Vim script again, so you don't get duplicate autocmds defined.  It's not there to clear settings set by a triggered autocmd.  You need to do that yourself in your autocmds.

Comment: Do you have a possible solution?

Comment: It's not clear to me why you need the options to be reset, since you're already using `setlocal`.  The options should not be inherited by new buffers.